# send a Report as a CSV/TEXT through HttpRequest

Tags: apex, callout, httprequest, csv, reports-api

i am new to salesforce programming ,
and i am trying to send a file through HttpRequest to a 3rd party .
the file i am trying to send is a report converted to csv format or text !! 
is there a way to do that ? 
and if there is at least tell me the functions or the classes that i need to use, or how to do it ?!

many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the contents of the report by using a PageReference:

```
String reportText = new PageReference('/'+reportId+'?csv=1').getContent().toString();
```

From there,  you can send the data to your third-party server:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
req.setBody(reportText);
req.setHeader('Content-Type','text/csv');
req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueOf(reportText.length()));
req.setMethod('POST');

HttpResponse response = new Http().send(req);
// Check for 200 status here
```

Note: You can only use this technique in synchronous, non-trigger context (so, a Visualforce page or RemoteAction/webservice/etc call). Batches, triggers, test methods, apex email services, and scheduled jobs aren't allowed to use getContent.

Comment: thank you my friend , you are awesome :) you are my savior :) , maybe you can help me with this too though , how do i overcome the 3MB limit when sending a post ?  is there some indirect way ?

Comment: @eassa The 3MB limit is a hard limit. You can't break it. If you had control of the receiving application, you could write a method that allows partial file transfers, and some systems might have a method of uploading parts of a file (like a sort of "resume" method), but that's typically pretty rare.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve report data using the Analytics API.  I'm not well versed with it, so I can only offer you the resource:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/

Comment: thx bro :) i will look into it :)